# Making browser vertical scrollbar return to top in ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Does anybody know how to make the vertical scrollbar the browser window return to the top in code?  Either javascript or code-behind would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it in JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:scroll(0,0);">Top</a>
```

Comment: This method works fine in IE 6/7/8, Safari 3.0, Chrome and FireFox 3.0